# How does index.php file stop viewing of folder structure in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I read that the file placed in wp-contents stops users from viewing the directory structure of WordPress. But the file is empty. How does it work?

```
<?php
// Silence is golden.
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you go to a directory, by default, most of the webservers first look for index file, be it `php` or `html` or anything else. In this specific case, when you go to that folder, `index.php` gets executed, even though it doesn't really have any code. It returns an empty page and request to load the folder is 'satisfied', thus preventing any further handling of said request.